# Is "put up coffee" idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

The movie Field of Dreams has a line:

> Annie: I'll **put up some coffee**. Why don't you go on outside.

Dictionaries don't seem to have this meaning. The Free Dictionary has entries on "provide funds", but I guess that's not the same as to provide coffee.

Comment: **Put up** can mean to present or to offer. Compare *Everyone agreed that their host had put up a fine spread*. I believe it means "I will bring us out some coffee" (i.e. serve coffee) rather than "I will start a pot of coffee going."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that this is a commonly used phrase anywhere. "*I'll put **on** some coffee*" is a much more idiomatic way of saying that one is about to begin brewing some coffee. A [Google Books search for "*put up some coffee*"](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&safe=off&tbm=bks&ei=5XrdWqDjI4nqjwTP4JfQAQ&q=%22put%20up%20some%20coffee%22) returns only ~16 results, one of which is quoting the movie *Field of Dreams*, and the others of which are almost exclusively found in a handful of trash novels. Compare this with [nearly 7,000 results for "*put on some coffee"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22put%20on%20some%20coffee%22). I would say that you are much more likely to be understood using the latter.